# oops private variable values does not return error

Tags: php

Why don't the code below return a value? I'm just getting a blank screen.

At least it should return some error, when i try private variable val in child class.

```
class Customer {

    private $instance_count = 0; //private data member
    function sub1(){
         return $this->instance_count++;
    }

}
class CustomerChild extends Customer{
    function sub2(){
         return $this->instance_count++;
    }

}
$CustomerObj = new CustomerChild();
print $CustomerObj->sub2();
```

Comment: but getting error when i use undefined variables, and when i access private method in child class.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private $instance_count = 0;
```

Change to

```
 protected $instance_count = 0;
```

Child classes can not access private variables. You want protected variables for that.

Also, your comment:

```
//static data member
```

That variable isn't static, not sure why comment is there.

Comment: I know it's private, that's your problem. "Child classes can not access private variables."  Protected vars can be accessed by child classes but not from outside, that's what you want instead.

Comment: note that this is not an error, the class will just use it's own (uninitialized) instance variable. for the reason of the blank screen see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that you are trying to print NULL:

```
var_dump($CustomerObj->sub2());
NULL

print NULL;
//nothing....
```

For details, check @James 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to turn on logging in php.ini and create the file you specified like so (for windows):

```
log_errors = On
error_log = C:\TEMP\PHP.LOG
```

Dont forget to create the folder, the file and enable writing privileges to that file.